# K3s pull images from Docker Pro private repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry, k3s

I'm attempting to use containers published to a private Docker Pro registry with K3s.

I've configured `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml`

```yaml
mirrors:
    docker.io:
        endpoint:
            - "https://docker.io"
configs:
    docker.io:
        auth:
            username: mydockerprouser
            password: dckr_pat_randomstuffgoeshere
```

Once deployed I restart k3s and check to see if crictl is configured to use a registry by running `sudo k3s crictl info`

```json
 "registry": {
      "configPath": "",
      "mirrors": {
        "docker.io": {
          "endpoint": [
            "https://docker.io"
          ],
          "rewrite": null
        }
      },
      "configs": {
        "docker.io": {
          "auth": {
            "username": "mydockerprouser",
            "password": "dckr_pat_randomstuffgoeshere",
            "auth": "",
            "identitytoken": ""
          },
          "tls": null
        }
      },
      "auths": null,
      "headers": null
    },
```

As a test I first applied the following manifest to k3s

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: troubleshooting
spec:
    containers:
        - name: troubleshooter
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          image: docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1
          command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
          args: [ "while :; do echo -n '.'; sleep 5 ; done" ]
```

From `kubectl describe pod troubleshooting` I see this error

```
Warning  Failed   60m (x4 over 61m)     kubelet  Failed to pull image "docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:7204e99bfb31a747dccaaac6d3e1599b008efa7cc31c2834b2623d2fba3a9c6a: not found
```

For a second test I ran `sudo k3s crictl pull --creds  docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1`

And I get

```
E0223 17:02:19.602354    7373 remote_image.go:171] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1\": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type
text/html for sha256:7060d74a8a8262817c2e5378288e2c2ba200e060c53e090bc7831c67de4cfafb: not found" image="docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1"
FATA[0000] pulling image: rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:7060d74a8a8262817c2e5378288e2c2ba200e060c53e090bc
7831c67de4cfafb: not found
```

If I remove the registries.yaml and run

```shell
sudo k3s crictl pull --creds "mydockerprouser:dckr_pat_randomstuffgoeshere" docker.io/mydockerprouser/troubleshooting:v1
```

It works!

Additional information

- Running K3s on fedora-coreos
- K3s version v1.26.1+k3s1